# How can I start this Node.JS application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

There is an open-source [application](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-diffing) which visually displays a difference between two BPMN diagrams.

I want to see what the application looks like when it runs.

How can I start it under Ubuntu?

I tried to run `node app.js` in the directory [bpmn-js-diffing/app](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-diffing/tree/master/app) but got the error

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at bpmn-js-diffing/app/app.js:6:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (bpmn-js-diffing/app/app.js:435:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
```

I looked at the [Gruntfile](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-diffing/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) in search of a "run" command, but only found these

```
grunt.registerTask('test', [ 'karma:single' ]);

grunt.registerTask('auto-test', [ 'karma:unit' ]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'jshint', 'test', 'browserify:standaloneViewer', 'jsdoc' ]);
```

To me they look like commands for running automated tests and generating documentation, not for running the actual application.

So how can I start this application?

**Update 1:** Ran `npm install` in `bpmn-js-diffing` directory. Then tried to run `node app.js` again (in the `bpmn-js-diffing/app`) directory. Here is the result:

```
bpmn-js-diffing/app$ node app.js 
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'bpmn-js-diffing'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at bpmn-js-diffing/app/app.js:9:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (bpmn-js-diffing/app/app.js:435:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
```

Comment: did you install node dependancies? npm install?

Comment: Looks like he didnt

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha `npm install` did not help. See *Update 1*.

Comment: `npm i bpmn-js-diffing`

Comment: I have as feeling the module is referencing itself with `bpmn-js-diffing`. What you could do is try replacing `Diffing = require('bpmn-js-diffing')` with `Diffing = require('.')` in `app.js`.

Or you could try symlinking the current folder to the `node_modules` folder. On *nix based systems you can do something like: `ln -sf $(pwd)/ ./node_modules/bpmn-js-diffing`, though I feel that's kind of an iffy solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a procedure to run this application

I finally found that you didn't even need to execute `npm install` command to run this project.
Indeed, the `app/bpmn-viewer.js` file embed all the necessary modules inside its source mapping.

> To display the code, either open the Sources tab in Chromium Developer tools or open the 3.2 MB file. The last line begins with `// # sourceMappingURL =`.
>   Copy and paste each character from `data: application / json; base64,`at the end of the line (`XX0 =`) in the address bar of a browser.

**Installation**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-diffing
$ cd bpmn-js-diffing
```

**Startup local HTTP server on port 7357**
Don't change dir, you must run this command in project root

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7357
```

**Run**

Open http://127.0.0.1:7357/app/ in a browser

**Demo (running on Ubuntu 18.04)**

[image: bpmn-js-diffing demo]

You can compare other files by loading them from `resources/` directory.

You can use any local HTTP server instead of the embedded python one, for example `live-server`.
Do do this, run the following commands at project root :

```
npm install live-server
./node_modules/.bin/live-server
```

Then browse to http://127.0.0.1:8080/app (default port `8080` can be changed, run `live-server --help` for more information)

Comment: Updated, it's finally much simplier than I thought to run the application. If the goal is to update, test and build the application, then you'll have to run `npm install` plus some more modules like `grunt, grunt-cli, karma, jsdoc, jshint`

Answer (score 5):

One big part of the Node.Js ecosystem is [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) which comes with NodeJS. This is how dependencies are managed.
Many NodeJS programs will have a [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file which describes various things about them, like for example what are their dependencies. By running [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) NPM will look at what packages the program needs, and install them automatically.

Comment: Thanks. This did not completely solve the problem. See *Update 1* in my question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install jquery module. 'npm i jquery'.

Comment: Thanks. This did not completely solve the problem. See *Update 1* in my question.

Answer (score 2):

In node js whenever you use `require('module_name')` it will search the node_module folder in your project directory or it can go to the global node_module folder. If the required module is not there, it will give **Cannot find module module_name**, you can do `npm i module_name` to resolve. also, you can save all the required dependencies in package.json folder by using `npm i module_name --save` command so that if you need to run the same code on the different environment you do not install each module separately you just need to do `npm i` and if will refer package.json folder and install a the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are trying to run a Node.js module.
I think the app you're trying to run is [this](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js)

> bpmn-js-diffing

is a module designed to be plugged into the above App.

Answer (score 2):

This is a web application not intended to run using NodeJS, but inside a browser. It manipulates the DOM with jQuery; **NodeJS does not have a DOM**. It uses [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/getting-started) and [Browserify](https://browserify.org/) to build the contents of the `/app` directory, but it already has the app built. If you want to rebuild it, you'll have to install grunt with `npm install -g grunt-cli` and executing `grunt --force` inside the project root, but you don't have to if you don't make any changes and just want to upload the application.

In order to have **the web application** working, you'll have to upload `/app`, `/assets` and `/resources` to a web root of an online web server and navigate to `https://<domain>/app/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:
 1. Replace `Diffing = require('bpmn-js-diffing');` with `Diffing = require('../index');` in you app.js file.
 2. install `npm i jsondiffpatch`
 3. `node app.js`